# Is it possible to clear my Visual Studio cache directly from visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, caching

I know how to clear my cache by deleting some file in a folder on my Windows machine.

I want to know if there is an easier way, like by clearing it directly from visual studio?

Comment: what kind of 'cache' are you talking about ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "cache": in most cases you should only be concerned with whats going on in your build directories, in which case you can simply use either the "clean" or a "rebuild" targets in the build menu.

Comment: I just added a new abstract method to my BasePage class, which all other pages in my app inherit from. So, when i try build i would expect a list of errors from all pages in my app cause the haven't implemented this method. The list errors is shown, that fine. When i try to click on an error so it takes me to the page, instead it takes me to a file in my Temporary ASP.NET Files folder on my machine. To my knowledge this is the cached version of that file.

Comment: Try doing a clean build like I said.  That said I know that MSVC does do some extra caching for ASP.NET but I'd try the simple option before looking further into that.

Comment: Thanks. I tried both options, but it doesn't clean every thing. I only get 1 or 2 files cleaned out of a whole bunch.